# Подписка на обновления на сервере RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rxjava

В приложении на сервер загружается картинка. Эту картинку надо скачать и отобразить, но проблема в том, что она ещё не успевает загрузиться в базу данных. Хочу исправить это с помощью **RxJava**. Читал,что можно подписать на обновления, тем самым узнать когда изображение загрузилось в бд. Помогите хотя бы псевдо кодом

Comment: Привет
давай поэтапно
1.Ты загружаешь картинку на сервер из приложения.
2. Далее ты хочешь в другом месте приложения её загрузить и сохранить в базу данных в приложении так?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я неправильно выразился здесь. Сервер = база данных. 1) загружаю картинку в базу данных. 2) в другом месте приложения скачать эту картинку и отобразить

Comment: На телефоне картинки лучше хранить как файлы, БД не для этого. В остальном как обычно при длительных операциях: создаете ее, подписываетесь на событие окончания, запускаете, как закончится подписчики получат уведомления. Rx или LiveData, корутины или WorkManager, примеров кода миллион в сети.

Comment: Я просто не нашёл примеры псевдо кода и тем более примеры самого кода. Вот и спрашиваю здесь